# Trim text to particular size

Tags: c#, xna

I have some text which I want to display in some sort of log at the bottom of the game.

I want a way of ensuring that the text fits in a particular size, and if its over that size, I'll trim it myself ("bla bla bl...")

I know that I can obtain the size that the text will take by using SpriteFont.MeasureString - so I know whether a particular string will overshoot the limit.

The most obvious solution involves a loop of this sort

```
StringBuilder display = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in string)
{
 if mySpriteFont.MeasureString((display.Append(c)) > SOMEAMOUNT
{
  display.append("...");
return display.toString();
}

}
```

However I'm afraid that this sort of thing is very expensive to do. Any other solutions?

Comment: Depending on your strings it may be faster to check the entire string first.  If there is no problem then return it, otherwise start trimming.

Comment: It also just occured to me that if I work backwards it'll save some loops too (provided overly long strings are the exception not the norm). But is there a better way?

Comment: Another idea is binary segmentation: instead of going character by character, first cut the string in half. If it fits, add a quarter back, if it doesn't cut it in half again, etc. The efficiency of this depends on the length of the strings and the size of the window.

Comment: @Rotem - I quite like that as a solution - put it as an Answer and we'll see if I get anything better. I'd need to see on whether slicing strings into pieces is more expensive than going through the characters.

Comment: You can cache the dimensions of an ellipsis in the selected font and use that along with an average character width to calculate an educated guess for the first round of trimming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to use MeasureString in there somewhere, it's just a case of the algorithm you use. The naiive solution is to just crop one character off the end until the string fits. A better one that has been suggested is to crop it in half, see if it fits, and home in on the solution that way. An alternative would measure the string length once, and then take an approximation based on the proportion of the string that is outside the boundaries. For example, if your limit is 100 pixels, and you have a string that is 400 pixels wide, crop of the last 3/4 of the string (in characters). Then, revert to the "factor of 2" approach, by removing or adding half the approximated string, and recursing until you are within one character. This should be fast enough for most occasions, and the approximation stage may well remove an initial overhead, particularly if your string is long, and in some cases may prove to give a result immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is applicable in `XNA` but in `C#` i would first check the length
`string.Length`
if it is greater than my limit then trim it using substring method

```
string newString;

your method
{
  if(string.Length > mylimit)
  {
    newString = yourString.Substring(0, 3);
  }
}
```

Comment: That would still work. But isn't string 'modification' very expensive since you (internally) need to create a new string each time?

Comment: You're talking apples and oranges.  The OP wants the measured size, you are calculating the length in the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to measure the length of a string it by `SpriteFont.MeasureString("text")`. It might be expensive if you do it every frame for a lot of strings, but if you do this only once and save the resulting string to some dictionary, array or a list, from where you can get them every frame, it will be much less expensive.

For example you have `"a very long string that doesn't fit into a small text box"`. You make it

```
a very long string
that doesn't fit
into a small text
box
```

and put it into a `Dictionary<string, string>` with the key of the initial string you were parsing. Then you can use it like this:

```
if (ParsedStringDic.ContainsKey(unparsedString))
    displayedString = ParsedStringDic[unparsedString];
else
    ParseString(unparsedString);
```